# How to split a character row, based on urls in R

Tags: r, regex, data-cleaning, strsplit

How to split a character row, based on urls? I have a column in a dataframe, where each row has text for more than 200-300 lines and contains a bunch of urls, special characters and numbers and so on. I am trying to clean this column.

Initial idea was to delete stop words and punctuations from the whole column, but then that messes up the existing urls in the text.

So 2nd approach was to split the text in multiple columns where the split happens at each url. One follow up question with respect to this is, wont the url position be different in each row, and hence still make it difficult to clean just the text?

Here is the sample text:

```
sample_text <- "Random text](https://random_url.com/image.png) --- more random text : - !!!!! (Numbers in the middle, versions 4.3.2.1 more random text ) [] --- //// more and more random text for another 300 lines. Line1 has some useful text , line 2 has a url, https://rstudio.com/maybe_has_some_version_files/2/image.png [ #] and continues for another 299 lines."
```

I did try strsplit() but it removes the urls from the text.

```
url_pattern <- "http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*,]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+|\\)$"  
split_string_1 <-  strsplit(sample_text, url_pattern, perl = TRUE)
```

Expected output should be :
split the string into multiple columns.

So my question is two part:

1. How to split a string and keep the url?
2. How to split the string and create new columns for each of those splits?

EDIT:

Yes, I don't want new columns, instead I am looking to clean the text and preserve the URL as is in it's location.

The question is:

- How to split the string, clean the rest of the text without messing up the URL's and preserve the URL's location in the text?

Comment: What is the actual output you expect here?  Does one line become multiple lines?  Something else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not quite, the expected output is to split the string into multiple columns. However, the other concern is, for the remaining rows, the split for a url may not occur at the same location, so how can I clean the text columns then? Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each line contains 2 URLs (else you can not store them in a standard data frame, since each line would require a different number of columns), you just need to find the position of the string "http(s)", and split the string at that position.

For this kind of task the base R functions `gregexpr()` and `regexec()` are well suited. For example:

```
gregexpr("https?", sample_text)
#> [[1]]
#> [1]  14 247
#> attr(,"match.length")
#> [1] 5 5
#> attr(,"index.type")
#> [1] "chars"
#> attr(,"useBytes")
#> [1] TRUE
```

This is a list, that will contain several elements if `sample_text` has several elements. The first entry contains the starting positions of the "http(s)" substrings. So then you an just use `substr()` to extract the new columns:

```
match_pos <- gregexpr("https?", sample_text)

# column 1
purrr::map2(sample_text, match_pos, ~ substring(.x, 1, .y[2]-1))
# column 2
purrr::map2(sample_text, match_pos, ~ substring(.x, .y[1], .y[2]-1))
# column 3
purrr::map2(sample_text, match_pos, ~ substring(.x, .y[2]))
```

Note that here I can hardcode the three columns, since there has to always be the same number.

EDIT: If the goal is to actually extract the URL, that same approach can be adapted. Here keeping the result in a list:

```r
sample_text <- "Random text](https://random_url.com/image.png) --- more random text : - !!!!! (Numbers in the middle, versions 4.3.2.1 more random text ) [] --- //// more and more random text for another 300 lines. Line1 has some useful text , line 2 has a url, https://rstudio.com/maybe_has_some_version_files/2/image.png [ #] and continues for another 299 lines."

match_pos <- gregexpr("https?://[[:alnum:]\\.\\-_\\/]+", sample_text)

url_starts <- lapply(match_pos, function(x) {attributes(x) <- NULL;x})
url_lengths <- lapply(match_pos, function(x) attr(x, "match.length"))
url_ends <- purrr::map2(url_starts, url_lengths, ~ .x+.y)

url_texts <- purrr::pmap(list(sample_text,url_starts, url_ends),
                             function(t,s,e) purrr::map2_chr(s,e, ~substr(t,.x,.y-1)))

url_texts
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "https://random_url.com/image.png"                            
#> [2] "https://rstudio.com/maybe_has_some_version_files/2/image.png"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I understand the usage of grepexpr, but the catch here is in your first statement, "Assuming that each line contains 2 URLs", this is unknown. Each row has unknown number of URLS, and that's why I couldn't create a dataframe, because as you mentioned, the number of columns need to be same, which may not be the case for every row. Also, there can also be instances where there are 2 urls next to each other, which will create 2 separate columns, but the next row may have text after every url.

Comment: Imagine this problem being, cleaning text with a bunch of URLS in it, and you want to preserve the URL along with their location in the text. There are 1000 rows in the dataframe, and each row has unknown number of urls, punctuations, numbers, white spaces in it.

Comment: If your expected output is not columns of a data frame, please clarify your question. If the goal is to preserve the url rather than split the string, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to make that edit. Yes, I am looking to preserve the URL and it's location in the text, but also clean the rest of the text. Your current answer does help me extract the url, but I loose it's position in the text. I had achieved this using, str_extract_all( sample_text, url_pattern), where I predefine url_pattern.

Comment: What do you call the position in the text? Is it literally the position (e.g. it's at the 45th character), or something else?

Comment: Here is the expected output: 
Random text https://random_url.com/image.png more random text Numbers in the middle versions 4.3.2.1 more random text more and more random text for another 300 lines Line1 has some useful text line 2 has a url https://rstudio.com/maybe_has_some_version_files/2/image.png and continues for another 299 lines

Notice, here the url remains in the same order as before, it’s just that the text has been cleaned a little, with no punctuations and extra spaces. That’s what I mean by position, the order in which the text and the url appears, I want to preserve that.

Comment: I was able to achieve this by writing a nested for loop, ie. by identifying urls in the text first, clean those, and then clean the rest of the text.